# Array/ArrayList OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
public static void getVegetableFromUser()
{
 String[] veg = SandwichDB.getVegetable();
    HashMap<String, String> getMapVegPrice = SandwichDB.getMapVegPrice();
    int vegSave = Validator.getInt(Scanner, "Select Vegetables [1, 8]: ", 1, 8);
    String v = veg[vegSave-1];
    sandwich.setVegetables(v);
}
```

Okay so the console prints out

> === Select Sandwich Vegetables ===
>   1 red onions $0.10
>   2 olives $0.10
>   3 pickles $0.10
>   4 lettuce $0.20
>   5 green peppers $0.25
>   6 tomatoes $0.30
>   7 cheese $0.49
>   8 Quit Vegetable Section
>   Select Vegetables [1, 8]:

The idea is to be able to pick multiple vegetables until I pick 8 which is quit vegetable section. How would I get about doing that?  With an else-if statement?

Also, vegetables is supposed to be an array, not an string...like on this line: `String v = veg[vegSave-1]`.

Here's the code on my SandwichDB.app:

```
public static String[] getVegetableInfo()
{
    ArrayList<String> vegsList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("vegetable.txt")))
    {
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            String[] elems = line.split("~");
            vegsList.add(elems[0] + " $" + elems[1]);
            line = in.readLine();
        }
        vegsList.add("Quit Vegetable Section");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    String[] vegetableInfo = vegsList.toArray(new String[]{});
    return vegetableInfo;
}
```

Comment: What does `getVegetable()` return exactly?  Does it return seven or eight elements?

Comment: yeah my bad i Didn't post that it returns all 8. I'm just having trouble with the repeat process, also when I pick 8 it should quit the section, instead it just adds "quit vegetable section" to the sandwich.setVegetable. Is it an else if statement or?

Comment: Did you have a question??  (You obviously didn't get an exception or you would have provided the stack trace and identified the statement where the exception occurred.)

Comment: If it doesn't return all eight...then why would you want to select from all eight?  That's probably the bug right there. :)

Comment: He means that option 8 is to exit the loop, not that he wants to choose 8 veggies

Comment: yeah what @ChrisGerken said, option 8 is to exit the loop, so it should be a if else statement? options 1-7 should select the veggies and repeat the menu so i Can select multiple veggies until i select 8 to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the rest of the code, but based on what you posted I would think that you are getting the arrayOutOfBoundsException because you are trying to get information about a vegetable that doesn't exist. Try adding an "if" to check if 8 was selected before executing this line:

```
String v = veg[vegSave-1];
```

Maybe try:

```
if(vegSave == 8){
    //TODO: Add code that quits vegetable section
} else {
    String v = veg[vegSave-1];
}
```

That way, if 8 was selected the program doesn't try to set String v equal to a vegetable.

Hope this helps, I wasn't too sure what exactly you wanted. (For example, was "also vegetables suppose to be an array not an string like on this line String v = veg[vegSave-1]." a question or a statement?)

Comment: The String v = veg[vegSave-1] yeah i'm suppose to change that line to an array. v suppose to be an array[]. thanks I'll try writing a if/else loop